# C Programming number representation through %x

Tags: c, hex, type-conversion

```
char*new_one_again = (address)
*new_one_again = 150;
printf("[%x]",  *new_one_again);
printf("[%d]", *new_one_again);

output: [ffffff96][-106]
```

I want it to print [150].

I realize that the hexadecimal representation presents the correct number if I get rid of the signed bits. However, I was wondering if there were any bit operations I could do to get 150 or really any integer number I put for my variable. I need the number 150 again in my later functions, but I get keep getting the hexadecimal number (a big number). Is there any way to fix this so I am returned 150 instead of the big number?

Comment: Um... You mean like `int somenum = 150; printf('%d\n', somenum);`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    unsigned char val ;
    unsigned char*  new_one_again = &val;
    *new_one_again = 150;
    printf("[%x]",  *new_one_again);
    printf("[%d]", *new_one_again);
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
[96][150]
```

Comment: Thank you! This is what I needed!